# Magento flat catalog advice wanted

Tags: magento, catalog

I'm having to convert an existing e-commerce site with 50k plus products to a magento site. Everywhere I look the advice is to use the flag catalog for this amount of products.

My question is, once enabled do new products have to be created using the old EAV tables or can I just import and update new products in the newly created flat catalog?

Thanks for any advice, I'm not looking forward to this transation at all, lol. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Think of Flat Catalog as a cache of the EAV structure. It does not replace the EAV system it simply creates a "flattened" or simplified version of the data store in EAV tables.

The EAV system is the most flexible way to store data, allowing any number of user or system variables without changes to the table structure. The down side is this system requires multiple and or recursive queries, this is slow and memory intensive. This is where the flat catalog comes in... The following is still quite accurate (even though it was written when flat catalog was first introduced) and quite clear: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/37247/#t122010

You will need to optimise memory usage within PHP and MySQL to enable rebuilding of flat catalog for a site with a large number of products.

Comment: @rsmarsha - This is a good description. EAV is THE data store for catalog product entities, and the info in the flat tables is derived (in part) therefrom.

Comment: Thanks Ben. It's a shame we can't switch to flat catalog and not have to update the old tables/rebuild. We have 50k+ products which have price/stock updated every half hour. On the current system it takes 5 mins to run the updates (php script run via a cronjob), it will be interesting to see how long it takes with the Magento setup.

Comment: Ooooch. For that, you'll have to generate 1st EAV, and my advice to you is to also insert data directly in flat tables. Don't let Magento do its indexation each 5 minutes. Well, it depends of course of how many products gets updated, if it's only 1 each 5' that's OK...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of Magento your using, but until 1.4 you need to put it into the EAV structure if you have to manage your products using backoffice.
The creation of the flat_ tables are automatic, it's part of the indexing process (which can be very long for this amount of products)

edit: I don't know for version after 1.4

Comment: The latest version will be used. I'm thinking Magento might not be suitable for this amount of products. The EAV model adds far too much overhead and due to amount of product options and suppliers we have it's looking like months and months of pain coming up. :(

Comment: This amount of product is fine with Magento. I know some project with 1M of products... You need to have sufficient resources, and more important a good caching system. //edit : by some, I mean 1 :p

Comment: By the way, if you have plenty of options, Magento is the way to go (to my mind at least). But I don't say that you'll spend less than 1 month of the project thought ;)

Comment: Well we have about 30 additional fields in our current product table and I'd say 20 of those are used for each product. It's not really product options as much as additional info for each product and flags. We sell consumer electronics so don't have options like colour, size etc. ;) The flag catalog is a nice idea but we update products every half hour via feeds and have product managers editing info all the time. Rebuilding that often sounds like a less than optimal way of doing things.

Comment: So it actually makes sense to use EAV on those products ;) EAV allow you to be more flexible with products fields (called Attributes in the EAV system) : you can have different set of attributes (e.g. a computer & a TV won't have the same attribute set), and you can easily add/remove some attribute even if you catalog is already imported.

Comment: What alternative solution do you think of? I'm not sure there are that many solutions offering the same amount of functionality and with better performances. I've been using Virtuemart once for smt like 25K products, I felt like I was in hell.

Comment: We currently get attributes from a 3rd party company (open range) and then build those out into a feed for our search engine (also 3rd party). So the specs for products are not stored in the main table. The attributes that are, are things like barcode, flags and some ebay info.

Comment: haven't really looked at other solutions yet. The company has agency managed sites running Magento already and wants me shift the site i work on over to it so future modules can be ported around.

Comment: guess i'm mostly concerned about the overhead from having to compile the catalog as often as we'll need to. I did find a post talking about how to update a product (including flag catalog table entries) by ID. I could run that after each update, either via auto script or manual updates in the backend.

Comment: I see. Then you don't have much choice here :p For the manual update, it's automatically  done, unless you doesn't want it (see in the backend -> index management or smt like that)